# Some apps not runing after snapd purge command

Tags: snap

I am completly new to Ubuntu.
I had not enough space and deleted some things, and also saw that in /var/lib/snapd/snaps are few firefox files, other apps had also few files there.
I used purge command and firefox didnt want to open.

Restarted laptop and then firefox was missing from favorites on the left.

Then used apt install snap and firefox apeard on favorites but didnt want to start.Small wheel icon/mouse pointer is runing for a few seconds, but firefox not opening.

Same gores for snap store, signal, vlc, but libre office is working normaly. And all files are still in snaps folder. They had red x icon, I changed permisson and now there is lock icon.

Can I revrse this or do I need to install ubuntu again?

Comment: It can probably be reversed. If your goal is to learn, then take the time to learn how to repair it. If your goal is to restore full functionality as quickly as possible, then reinstall.